# Search a value in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

I have a database file, csv file. I want to search a name in this list. To know if it exist or not. If not display an option to add. The number next to the name is the client number. How I search a value in this list?

```
lines=[]
user_name=input("PLEASE ENTER YOUR FIRST AND LAST NAME: ")
with open("data_base.csv", "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        row = line.split(",")
        for i in range(1, len(row)):
            row[i] =eval(row[i])
            lines.append(row)
```

If I print the list the result is the next one:

```
[['Mariana Ortigoza', 1], ['James Butt', 2], ['Josephine Darakjy', 3], ['Art Venere', 4], ['Lenna Paprocki', 5], ['Donette Foller', 6], ['Simona Morasca', 7], ['Mitsue Tollner', 8], ['Leota Dilliard', 9], ['Sage Wieser', 10]]
```

Comment: I suggest saving that data into a dict, with the name as the key and the number as the value. That's much more efficient for searching.

Comment: BTW, it's a **bad** idea to use `eval` to convert data like that, and totally unnecessary. A malicious person could put commands into the CSV that if `evaluated` could format your HD, etc.

Comment: Can you post a sample csv file?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `operator.itemgetter` to extract the first element of each sublist.

Then test if the input name is in a `set` of names; if not then append to `lines`.

```
from operator import itemgetter

lines = [['Mariana Ortigoza', 1], ['James Butt', 2], ['Josephine Darakjy', 3],
         ['Art Venere', 4], ['Lenna Paprocki', 5], ['Donette Foller', 6],
         ['Simona Morasca', 7], ['Mitsue Tollner', 8], ['Leota Dilliard', 9],
         ['Sage Wieser', 10]]

user_name = input("PLEASE ENTER YOUR FIRST AND LAST NAME: ")

if user_name not in set(map(itemgetter(0), lines)):
    lines.append([user_name, len(lines)+1])
```

Comment: I'd do similar, except use `csv.reader` (I think the names are in quotes) and uppercase the names for a case-insensitive compare. Something like `set(row[0].upper() for row in csv.reader(open('data_base.csv', newline='')))`